# Stuck on Windows Boot Manager Loop

Tags: windows-7, bootloader

I initiated a Repair using my windows 7 setup on a USB stick but after restarting I am stuck in this screen:

[image]

Rebooting from USB would return to this screen instead of starting win setup. How do I fix this without creating a DVD disk?

Answer (score 0):

You need to boot through USB/DVD with Windows 7 and select "Repair your computer".

And in System recovery options window, click and open Command Prompt

Once open run these two commands:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
```

---

Tools you can use to make a bootable USB/DVD:

1. Universal USB Installer
2. Windows 7 USB DVD download tool

Comment: Thats the problem. I have already initiated "Repair" and after restarting I am stuck on this loop. Hitting F12 and selecting boot from USB goes back to this screen.

Comment: Are you getting this error while booting from USB?

Comment: Are you choosing the USB as the boot source in BIOS? F8 at boot [which can be difficult to make work on a modern machine with an SSD, you need to time it just right ]

Comment: @Saurabh Sharma Unfortunately yes. Is it possible to remove the harddisk, put it in an enclosure, and do the repair from another PC?

Comment: @kosinix Unplug the USB and then try to boot once

Comment: @Tetsujin F8 is safe mode right? F12 is for the boot option on this pc. Its old school HDD not SSD. Booting from USB goes to that screen.

Comment: F8/F12 can depend on the bios, I think. Mine are all F8, all asus machines, a few years old.

Comment: @Saurabh Tetsujin Nevermind. I found the culprit. I opened the laptop and found that the harddisk was removed from its port. Totally unrelated. I should probably delete the question since the cause is unrelated to windows. Thank you for all your help